# Collision detection for race course in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection

i am wondering how could I detect collision on the course given in the attached image for example:

[image: race course]

In XNA that could be done easily but i dunno how to make it possible in OpenGLES for such scenario as simple collision with rectangles is not a big deal but for this case I need help.

Answer (score 3):

Opengl doesn't support any native collision detection, its just a polygon rendering utility.  If you wanted to preform collision detection on the given image, you could set up an edge finder, and then load the detected edges into your own custom collision detection algorithm - but that has nothing to do with opengl or opengles.

Comment: could you gimme a some link to a good tutorial covering the concerned issue ??

Comment: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html for opengles
@genpfault also has a good suggestion on collision detection, and here is an intro tutorial: http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Basic_Collision_Detection.shtml.  That issue is more what you personally want/need rather than an existing standard or example.

Comment: thank you, but i am looking for something more related to my requirements :)

Comment: Opengl will not do any form of collision detection so we are providing alternatives.  Please clarify your requirements / question.

Answer (score 0):

For collision *detection* a simple and *very* dirty solution is to map your player position to the bitmap's coordinate system and check the pixel color/value.  Grey is on-course, white is off.

Collision *response* is a whole other question :)

Comment: thanks for response, idea is ok but i need some more simpler solution :)

Comment: @MGD: That's about as simple as it gets.  The next step up is a [point-in-polygon test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon), after [auto-vectorizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28computer_graphics%29#Vectorization_algorithms) your course map.